# python web scraping: output empty lists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use python to webscrap information from a car website to have name & price.
but the output is empty lists

car website: https://www.contactcars.com/en/cars/used/toyota?page=1&sortOrder=false&sortBy=CreatedAt

my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_page = requests.get("https://www.contactcars.com/en/cars/used/toyota?page=1&sortOrder=false&sortBy=CreatedAt").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page)

data = []
for x in soup:
  name = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'n-engine-card__model ng-star-inserted'})
  price= soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'n-engine-card__price'})

  data.append({
        'name':name,
        'price':price
    })
  
print(data)
```

output:

```
[{'name': [], 'price': []}, {'name': [], 'price': []}]
```

Comment: Can you do a quick sanity check? Remove the attrs from `soup.find_all` and check if it produces any output.

Comment: data in `script` block whit `id="serverApp-state"`

Comment: @ZiadAmerr when remove all Attr , it give a long list, this list doesn't include any info related to the cars

Comment: It looks like the .text does not contain the html, this is generated by JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from tabulate import tabulate

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
}

url = "https://www.contactcars.com/en/cars/used/toyota?page=1&sortOrder=false&sortBy=CreatedAt"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = (
    BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    .find("script", {"id": "serverApp-state"})
    .text
    .replace("&q;", '"')
)
search = "http_requests:https://api.live.contactcars.com/gateway/vehicles/carsSearch/used"
data = json.loads(soup)[search]["body"]["result"]["items"]

table = []
for item in data:
    table.append(
        [
            item['make']['nameEn'],
            item['model']['nameEn'],
            item['year'],
            item['price'],
        ]
    )

print(
    tabulate(
        table,
        headers=['Make', 'Model', 'Year', 'Price'],
        tablefmt='github',
    )
)
```

Output:

```
| Make   | Model    |   Year |   Price |
|--------|----------|--------|---------|
| Toyota | Corolla  |   2022 |  650000 |
| Toyota | Yaris    |   2007 |  225000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   1998 |  110000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   2018 |  490000 |
| Toyota | Fortuner |   2017 |  900000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   2020 |  600000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   2021 |  750000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   2020 |  630000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   1993 |   88000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   1995 |   90000 |
| Toyota | Corolla  |   2013 |  410000 |
| Toyota | Hiace    |   2007 |  280000 |
```